# Iterate array of object to merge new object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

I'm trying to create new object with array. I've already try it using lodash map. But my problem is how do i get the product_ids in specific collection and put it in array.

This is the object

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": "b7079be6-c9ab-4d24-9a1d-38eddde926c2",
      "collection": "mortgages",
      "product_id": "854174665132787596022"
    },
    {
      "id": "0da12779-6fe9-45d5-afbf-91d2466e5b7e",
      "collection": "mortgages",
      "product_id": "304285269353822734222"
    },
    {
      "id": "87a137ba-5f66-4e94-8d5d-698dfbaa08ec",
      "collection": "mortgages",
      "product_id": "-304414504724243127922"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "522f4b83-4c5a-4ffe-836d-33a51325d251",
      "collection": "carinsurance",
      "product_id": "10413803"
    },
    {
      "id": "02b79566-9cf7-48fa-a8d3-eecf951b5a76",
      "collection": "carinsurance",
      "product_id": "10397803"
    }
  ]
]
```

I've already tried this code

```
map(this.products, (item, key) => {
   this.arr.push({
      collection: item[0].collection,
      product_ids: item.product_id
   });
});
```

I want to have a result like this.

```
{
    "collection": "mortgages",
    "product_ids": [
        "304285269353822734222",
        "854174665132787596022",
        "-304414504724243127922"
    ]
},
{
    "collection": "carinsurance",
    "product_ids": [
        "10413803",
        "10397803"
    ]
}
```

But I am getting this result. Can somebody help me to this one.

```
{
    "collection": "mortgages",
    "product_ids": undefined
},
{
    "collection": "carinsurance",
    "product_ids": undefined
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`item` in your case is an array, but you are accessing it as if there was a `product_id` field on the array itself, you'll have to map all `product_id` properties from each item in the array:

```
map(this.products, (item, key) => {
   return {
      collection: item[0].collection,
      product_ids: item.map(i => i.product_id)
   };
});
```

Also, if the map function returns an array, for each item in the initial array it transforms it into a new format, so you can return and assign to `this.arr` instead of pushing to `this.arr` within the map function.

Comment: This will only work if we know all the collection properties are the same in each node. It will work in OP posted data set but not in all possible data sets.

Comment: This is what I am looking for. You are right I forgot to map the product_id. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested reduce functions.

```js
const collect = data => data.reduce((results, item) => {
  item.reduce((results, subItem) => {
    const current = results.find(i => i.collection === subItem.collection);
    if (current) {
      current.product_ids.push(subItem.product_id);
    } else {
      results.push({ collection: subItem.collection, product_ids: [subItem.product_id] });
    }
    return results;
  }, results);
  return results;
}, []);

const data = [
  [
    {
      "id": "b7079be6-c9ab-4d24-9a1d-38eddde926c2",
      "collection": "mortgages",
      "product_id": "854174665132787596022"
    },
    {
      "id": "0da12779-6fe9-45d5-afbf-91d2466e5b7e",
      "collection": "mortgages",
      "product_id": "304285269353822734222"
    },
    {
      "id": "87a137ba-5f66-4e94-8d5d-698dfbaa08ec",
      "collection": "mortgages",
      "product_id": "-304414504724243127922"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "522f4b83-4c5a-4ffe-836d-33a51325d251",
      "collection": "carinsurance",
      "product_id": "10413803"
    },
    {
      "id": "02b79566-9cf7-48fa-a8d3-eecf951b5a76",
      "collection": "carinsurance",
      "product_id": "10397803"
    }
  ]
];

console.log(collect(data));
```